# Unable to read cookie in php

Tags: php, cookies

I am creating cookies in a `loginform.php` file like this :

```
$time = time();
setcookie('myusername', $myusername, $time +60*60*24*200); // Sets the cookie username
setcookie('myuserid', $rows['userid'], $time +60*60*24*200); // Sets the cookie password
setcookie('myname', $rows['name'], $time +60*60*24*200);
```

this file is located in a folder named `login` which is located in the root directory of my website.

I am able to retrieve the cookies in `loginform.php` but not at anyother file in the root directory ..

What may be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [manual](http://php.net/setcookie),

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

You need to set the cookie path to `/` to access it from anywhere. So it'll be like,

```
setcookie('myusername', $myusername, $time +60*60*24*200, '/');
```

**Its not a good idea to set sensitive information like username or user id in cookie. Any one can change the value and become someone else.**

Its better to use [Session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Even the session id will be saved in cookie but its hard to guess another session id.

Answer (score 3):

when a cookie is created its root path is set to the path of the script that created, in this case /login - everything below that cannot access the cookie,  add '/' as another parmeter in your setcookie

```
$time = time();
setcookie('myusername', $myusername, $time +60*60*24*200, '/'); // Sets the cookie username
setcookie('myuserid', $rows['userid'], $time +60*60*24*200, '/'); // Sets the cookie password
setcookie('myname', $rows['name'], $time +60*60*24*200, '/');
```